# mysql check if user exist > 0

Tags: php, mysql

```
$check_select = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fblogin` WHERE email = '$user_email'")); 

if($check_select > 0)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `fblogin` (fb_id, name, email, image, postdate) VALUES ('$user_fbid', '$user_fnmae', '$user_email', '$user_image', '$now')");
```

The code I took from somewhere online, I'm  just curious if it's correct at `if($check_select > 0)`, I think it should be `if($check_select != 0)`, right?

Comment: Yes and did you try or not ?

Comment: you should have the `mysql_query` outside of the `mysql_num_rows` as you do not know if the query will fail, and if it fails its not going to return a mysql result object and then `mysql_num_rows` is going to throw an error because you are not passing a mysql result object. And of course do not use `mysql` api use `mysqli` as `mysql` api is depreciated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: it would actually work with > 0 as well as with != 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above will work, if is basically saying if the $check_user is above 0, which is the same as saying if the $check_user is not equal to 0.

I have used this code before, and here is what I did with it:

**THIS IS BASED ON IF YOU ARE CREATING A NEW USER**

You have to connect to your DB in the Mysql_query, and I recommend using mysqli, not mysql:

```
// CONNECT TO THE SERVER
$sql_con = mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);

// RUN THE QUERY ON YOUR DATABASE
$check_user = mysqli_query($sql_con, "SELECT * FROM `fblogin` WHERE email = '$user_email'");

// GET NUMBER OF USERS FOUND
$check_user_num = mysqli_num_rows($check_user);

// IF NO USER EXISTS IN DATABASE DO THE FOLLOWING
if($check_user_num = 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `fblogin` (fb_id, name, email, image, postdate) VALUES ('$user_fbid', '$user_fnmae', '$user_email', '$user_image', '$now')");
} else {
    // ELSE DO THIS CODE HERE (for me, I normally redirect with an error code, like the following:)
    header('location:?error=exists');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password");


$check_select = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `fblogin` WHERE email = '$user_email'"); 

$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($check_select);

if($numrows > 0){
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `fblogin` (fb_id, name, email, image, postdate) VALUES ('$user_fbid', '$user_fnmae', '$user_email', '$user_image', '$now')");
}
```